# why rxjs keeps not being the right version?

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, cloud9

I'm trying to install a node/angular2 solution on cloud9.  Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "example",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "typings": "typings",
    "vendor": "gulp vendor",
    "gulp": "gulp clean && gulp",
    "build:production": "gulp clean && gulp build && node systemjs.builder.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/forms": "0.3.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "body-parser": "~1.15.2",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "debug": "~2.2.0",
    "express": "~4.14.0",
    "hbs": "~3.1.0",
    "mongoose": "^4.5.8",
    "mongoose-unique-validator": "^1.0.2",
    "morgan": "~1.6.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.11",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.3.0",
    "systemjs": "0.19.36",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "del": "^2.2.1",
    "gulp": "^3.9.0",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.6.0",
    "gulp-typescript": "^2.10.0",
    "systemjs-builder": "^0.15.26",
    "typings": "^1.3.2"
  }
}
```

In spite of how this is written, I keep getting this error during `npm install`:

```
npm WARN @angular/http@2.0.0-rc.5 requires a peer of rxjs@5.0.0-beta.6 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/router@3.0.0-rc.1 requires a peer of rxjs@5.0.0-beta.6 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/core@2.0.0-rc.5 requires a peer of rxjs@5.0.0-beta.6 but none was installed.
```

when I try to run the solution I keep getting this error:

```
 UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY rxjs@5.0.0-beta.11
```

I tried changing the package.json to beta.6, and it still fails.

does anyone have any wisdom on this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Update `package.json` to use `"rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",`
2. Delete `node_modules` directory in project folder.
3. Run `npm install`

That should fix it. I use your `package.json` with rxjs 5 beta6, the installation was successful without any issue.